# Send checked check-boxes in request to server - ASP.NET jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, checkbox

I have a table with three columns, First name, Last name and a checkbox column.
The user have the option to check  a checkbox(es). I'm trying to send a request to my web server for each checked checkbox. I have to check at server side which checkboxes are checked in order to delete the checked rows from the table DB. Need to do that with **jQuery**.

What is wrong with my ajax code..? how can I retrieve the data about the checked checkboxes at the code behind?.

```
<script>
// Add row to the table of data
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#addPersonBtn").on("click", function () {
    $('table').append('<tr> <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" ></td><td>שם משפחה<input type="text" name="LastName"></td><td>שם פרטי <input type="text" name="FirstName"></td> </tr>');
});

// Remove checked table rows 
$("#deletePersonBtn").on("click", function () {
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});

jQuery(function ($) {
     $("#deletePersonBtn").click(function () {
         //create an array of checked checkbox ids
         var ids = $('.css-checkbox_latest:checked').map(function (index) {
         return this.id;
     }).get();

     //if nothing is selected alert the user and stop further processing
     if (!ids.length) {
         alert('nothing is selected')
         return;
     }

     //send a request to server using an ajax POST request, it will contains an array of parameters called ids
     $.ajax({
          url: '<url>',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              ids: ids
          }
     })
   });
});
})
```

Comment: You have two handlers that handle the click of the deletePersonBtn button. First one deletes the closest 'tr' next one is doing something else. 

Maybe you better combine them ?

Comment: Thanks! did it but still not working:(

Comment: You should debug the code and see where it is failing. 
First check if ids is populated correctly, if yes - check if the URL of the ajax post is correct, etc.